# Postgres trigger doesn't work with insert

Tags: postgresql

I have trigger before insert and seem like it doesn't work.

Here is my trigger/function.

If new column is null, it would point to record "unknown" and fill the another column insert as sysdate.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION
"ECISDRDM"."TRIGGER_FCT_TR_APPLICATION_CDIM_INS"()
    RETURNS trigger AS $BODY$

declare     v_ErrorCode int;    v_ErrorMsg  varchar(512);
    v_Module    varchar(32) := 'TR_APPLICATION_CDIM_INS';

begin       ----    -- If this is an INSERT operation   ----    
if TG_OP = 'INSERT' then        ----        -- This just ensures that the filename is not null      ----        
if NEW.mig_filename is null then
           NEW.mig_filename := 'Unknown';       end if;
                NEW.mig_insert_dt   := now();   end if;

    ----    -- Exception error handler  ----    exception   when others then
        v_ErrorCode := SQLSTATE;        v_ErrorMsg  := SQLERRM;

        insert into ecisdrdm.errorlog(tstamp, 
            os_user,host,module,errorcode,errormsg)         values
            (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, sys_context('userenv','session_user'),
            sys_context('userenv','host'), v_Module, v_ErrorCode, v_ErrorMsg);      
  RETURN NEW; 
end $BODY$ 
language 'plpgsql';

CREATE TRIGGER "TR_APPLICATION_CDIM_INS" BEFORE INSERT ON
"ECISDRDM"."APPLICATION_CDIM" FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE
    "ECISDRDM"."TRIGGER_FCT_TR_APPLICATION_CDIM_INS"() ;
```

inside the code should I fill the trigger BEFORE INSERT trigger or AFTER INSERT trigger?  I have tried both and none of them work.   Any advise? thank you.

Comment: `sys_context('userenv','host')`  is invalid in Postgres.

Comment: if sys_context('userenv','host') is invalid in Postgres, then may I ask what is the corrected one to add the system context in it?

Comment: What do you expect that function to do?

Comment: the new correct function you gave is still not work.

the function needs to give the mig_insert_date current_date for insert, if the mig_filename is null it should give "unknown".

your provide corrected script is still not work. when I do the new insert.  Both mig_filename, and mig_insert_dt are null.